# JTable is not showing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?  It's not showing anything except the menu and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

```
 public class ProfesorSelect extends JFrame {
    public ProfesorSelect(Profesor profesor){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("Logout");
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        fileMenu.add(newItem);
        fileMenu.add(open);
        setName(profesor.toString() + " /Profesor");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        for(Clasa clasa: Centralizator.getInstance().getClase()){
            JPanel panelClasa = new JPanel();
            panelClasa.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelClasa,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            JLabel numeClasa = new JLabel(clasa.getIdClasa());
            ArrayList<String> elevi = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Elev elev : clasa.getElevi()){
                elevi.add(elev.toString());
            }
            JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(new JList(elevi.toArray()));
            panelClasa.add(numeClasa);
            panelClasa.add(jScrollPane);
            scrollPanel.add(panelClasa);
        }
        add(scrollPanel);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The code would need a `main(String[])` and imports to be an MCVE.

Comment: Aw hell, you got to be kidding me,... your code doesn't even have a JTable in it. Seriously? Please improve this question a *lot* or delete it.

Comment: `Centralizator`  and of course you would need to either include that class, or factor it out completely to show an MCVE..

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `scrollPane.add` this is not how scroll panes are used.

Take a look at [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)